# DNS Query in C++ Not Receiving Answer Records

Tags: c++, networking, dns

I'm working on a DNS query program in C++ that sends a DNS query to a server and receives a response. However, I'm having trouble receiving answer records in the response. The response header and question section seem correct, but the answer section is always empty.

Here's a part of my code where should be mistake:

```cpp
struct DnsOptions {
    bool recursionDesired;  // Whether recursion is desired in the DNS query
    bool reverseQuery;      // Whether it's a reverse DNS query
    bool useAAAA;           // Whether to use AAAA record type
    string server;          // DNS server address
    int port;               // DNS server port
    string address;         // DNS query address
};

// DNS header structure
struct DNSHeader {
    uint16_t id;        // DNS message ID
    uint16_t flags;     // DNS message flags
    uint16_t qdcount;   // Number of entries in the question section
    uint16_t ancount;   // Number of resource records in the answer section
    uint16_t nscount;   // Number of name server resource records in the authority records section
    uint16_t arcount;   // Number of resource records in the additional records section
};

// DNS question structure
struct DNSQuestion {
    string qname;       // Domain name being queried
    uint16_t qtype;     // Type of the query
    uint16_t qclass;    // Class of the query
};

// DNS answer structure
struct DNSAnswer {
    string name;        // Domain name to which this resource record pertains
    uint16_t type;      // Type of the resource record
    uint16_t rclass;    // Class of the resource record
    uint32_t ttl;       // Time to live for this resource record
    uint16_t rdlength;  // Length of the resource data field
    string rdata;       // Resource data
};


bool receiveAndParseDnsResponse(int sockfd, const DnsOptions& options) {
    vector<uint8_t> responseBuffer(4096); 
    sockaddr_in serverAddr{};
    socklen_t serverAddrLen = sizeof(serverAddr);
 
    
    ssize_t bytesRead = recvfrom(sockfd, responseBuffer.data(), responseBuffer.size(), 0, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&serverAddr), &serverAddrLen);
    
    if (bytesRead == -1) {
        cerr << "Error receiving DNS response: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return false;
    }else if(bytesRead == 0) {
        cerr << "Received an empty DNS response." << endl;
        return false;
    }

    cout << "Received " << bytesRead << " bytes of DNS response." << endl;
    cout << "ResponseBuffer Contents:" << endl;
    for (ssize_t i = 0; i < bytesRead; ++i) {
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << static_cast<int>(responseBuffer[i]) << " ";
        if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0) {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    return true;
}
bool sendDnsQuery(const DnsOptions& options, const string& queryName, int queryType) {
  
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        cerr << "Error creating socket: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return false;
    }

   
    sockaddr_in serverAddr{};
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(options.port);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, options.server.c_str(), &(serverAddr.sin_addr)) <= 0) {
        cerr << "Error setting server address" << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return false;
    }

    
    vector<uint8_t> queryPacket;

   
    DNSHeader header;
    header.id = htons(1234); // ID může být libovolné číslo
    header.flags = htons(options.recursionDesired ? 0x0100 : 0x0000); // Recursion Desired
    header.qdcount = htons(1); // Jedna dotazovací sekce
    header.ancount = 0;
    header.nscount = 0;
    header.arcount = 0;

    queryPacket.insert(queryPacket.end(), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&header), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&header) + sizeof(DNSHeader));

    
    DNSQuestion question;
    question.qname = queryName;
    question.qtype = htons(queryType);
    question.qclass = htons(1); // IN (Internet)

    vector<string> parts;
    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = question.qname.find('.')) != string::npos) {
        string part = question.qname.substr(0, pos);
        parts.push_back(part);
        question.qname.erase(0, pos + 1);
    }
    parts.push_back(question.qname); // Zbylá část jména

   
    for (const string& part : parts) {
        queryPacket.push_back(part.length()); // Length of the part
        queryPacket.insert(queryPacket.end(), part.begin(), part.end()); // Characters of the part
    }
    queryPacket.push_back(0); // Konec QNAME
    queryPacket.push_back(0); // High byte of QTYPE
    queryPacket.push_back(question.qtype); // Low byte of QTYPE
    queryPacket.push_back(0); // High byte of QCLASS
    queryPacket.push_back(question.qclass); // Low byte of QCLASS

  
    ssize_t bytesSent = sendto(sockfd, queryPacket.data(), queryPacket.size(), 0, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr));
    if (bytesSent == -1) {
        cerr << "Error sending DNS query: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return false;
    }

    if (static_cast<size_t>(bytesSent) != queryPacket.size()) {
        cerr << "Not all bytes of the DNS query were sent." << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return false;
    }

 
    bool success = receiveAndParseDnsResponse(sockfd, options);

    close(sockfd);

    return success;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    DnsOptions options = parseCommandLine(argc, argv); // parsing arguments here to struct options

    bool success = sendDnsQuery(options, options.address, options.useAAAA ? 28 : 1); 
    
    if (!success) {
        cerr << "DNS query failed." << endl;
        return 1;   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And basically here is an example when I run it on some server with query address and in the output data there is no query answer:

```
Received 34 bytes of DNS response.
ResponseBuffer Contents:
04 d2 81 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 77 77 77 
03 66 69 74 05 76 75 74 62 72 02 63 7a 00 00 00 
00 00
```

And there is nothing wrong with a server. Dig command works corrrectly.

Comment: Great job dumping the received response, byte at a time. Did you do the same for the query packet, and verify that it complies with RFC 1035, ***exactly***?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am dumping it in recive function I posted just first part of it where is the problem

Comment: I asked about the query packet. I don't see any code which dumps it. When I implemented my own DNS resolver, that's what I did: dumped the query packet, and kept staring at it until I figured out what's wrong with it. Dump the query packet. Compare it with what `dig` sends, as captured by `strace` and/or `tcpdump`. Compare. Find the difference. Fix it. Problem solved.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the problem is that I cant compare it to anything coz I dont get any answer with which I can compare it

Comment: Who said anything about comparing answers? The first sentence in my previous comment clearly says "query packet".